# How long to train cifar10 in tensorflow with a GTX 960

Tags: tensorflow

Could someone else tell me how long it took them to train the model on their machine? I've posted a little bit of the logging information from the code below. `top` shows ~300% cpu usage for python, and `nvidia-smi` had been showing `Volatile GPU-Util` at ~60% yesterday, but now it is about 30%. Started training 30 hours ago, and the loss has been oscillating around 0.10 for about 15 hours now. I might need to tweak the cutoff parameters for the gradient descent, but I expected the code to run and converge as it was in the tutorial repo.  I followed the tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn), where they say

> This model achieves a peak performance of about 86% accuracy within a
>   few hours of training time on a GPU

```
>>> head -n20 nohup.out
...
2017-05-14 16:38:21.763013: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:887] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 960
major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.342
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 1.95GiB
Free memory: 1.58GiB
2017-05-14 16:38:21.763029: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:908] DMA: 0 
2017-05-14 16:38:21.763036: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 0:   Y 
2017-05-14 16:38:21.763044: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 960, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)

Successfully downloaded cifar-10-binary.tar.gz 170052171 bytes.
Filling queue with 20000 CIFAR images before starting to train. This will take a few minutes.
2017-05-14 16:38:36.943404: step 0, loss = 4.68 (83.0 examples/sec; 1.542 sec/batch)
2017-05-14 16:38:37.983802: step 10, loss = 4.60 (1230.3 examples/sec; 0.104 sec/batch)
2017-05-14 16:38:39.199938: step 20, loss = 4.55 (1052.5 examples/sec; 0.122 sec/batch)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The training seems to be able to run as long as you want. You kill the training script when you get the loss you want, just make sure that the training has generated a checkpoint file recently. For me the checkpoint files were in /tmp/cifar10_train.

First I tried `kill -SIGSTOP <pid>`. As they mentioned in the tutorial, this didn't leave enough memory for the evaluation script, so I terminated the training script with ```kill -9 . Then I ran the evaluation script and got the 86% accuracy they mentioned in the tutorial.

`2017-05-15 22:39:35.574805: precision @ 1 = 0.865`