# CIFAR10 example running time

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I have been learning ML using TensorFlow for a few weeks. I have been following the tutorials given on the TensorFlow website ([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn)). I started with training the model and it has been running on the system with the following specifications(it was taken before training started therefore showing minimal usage)[image]

It has completed more than 200,000 steps so for how long should it be running or is there anything I am missing here.

Also, a similar question was found on the forum [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991501/how-long-to-train-cifar10-in-tensorflow-with-a-gtx-960). I could not find any reference on TensorFlow website where it says that you have to terminate it yourself when you get the desired loss. Even if it is so, how to determine what is the value of loss where you can stop the training?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, there's no such fixed loss or anything by which you can say, you have a best model. It depends on training samples how simple/complex it is to train. Sometime 200k step might be more than enough and sometime not. Higher number of iteration causes over-fitting of the model and less causes under-fitting. But somehow you can use validation and test set to evaluate the model.